# Flutter Positioning Assistance

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to position this circular expandable button to the bottom-right of the screen. I know I can add MainAxisAlignment: Alignment.end or whatever, but that makes it so that only half the button is clickable. Is there any other way to do it?

Here is an image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wABo.png)

Here is my code:

```
                 Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height - size.height * .11,
                    width: size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            if (_isExpanded)
                              _buildOptionButton(Icons.dangerous, 'Dangerous'),
                            if (_isExpanded)
                              _buildOptionButton(Icons.delete, 'Delete'),
                            if (_isExpanded)
                              _buildOptionButton(Icons.edit, 'Edit'),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: size.height * .11,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () => {
                                        setState(() => {
                                              _isExpanded = !_isExpanded,
                                              _isOptionButtonVisible =
                                                  !_isExpanded,
                                              if (_isExpanded)
                                                {_animationController.forward()}
                                              else
                                                {_animationController.reverse()}
                                            })
                                      }, // Corrected onPressed callback
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                                    primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 100),
                                  ),
                                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                    animation: _animationController,
                                    builder: (context, child) {
                                      return Transform.rotate(
                                        angle: _animationController.value *
                                            0.5 *
                                            3.1415,
                                        child: Icon(
                                          _isExpanded ? Icons.close : Icons.add,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

EDIT: Here is the _buildOptionButton method

```
Widget _buildOptionButton(IconData iconData, String tooltip) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 100),
        heroTag: tooltip,
        onPressed: () {
          print('Action performed for $tooltip');
        },
        tooltip: tooltip,
        child: Icon(iconData),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0.8),
              child: Container(
                height: size.height - size.height * .11,
                width: size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        if (_isExpanded)
                          _buildOptionButton(Icons.dangerous, 'Dangerous'),
                        if (_isExpanded)
                          _buildOptionButton(Icons.delete, 'Delete'),
                        if (_isExpanded)
                          _buildOptionButton(Icons.edit, 'Edit'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * .11,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () => {
                                    setState(() => {
                                          _isExpanded = !_isExpanded,
                                          _isOptionButtonVisible =
                                              !_isExpanded,
                                          if (_isExpanded)
                                            
             {_animationController.forward()}
                                          else
                                            
                 {_animationController.reverse()}
                                        })
                                  }, // Corrected onPressed callback
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                                primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 
                   100),
                              ),
                              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: _animationController,
                                builder: (context, child) {
                                  return Transform.rotate(
                                    angle: _animationController.value *
                                        0.5 *
                                        3.1415,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      _isExpanded ? Icons.close : 
             Icons.add,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Here you can use Align. On alignment which holds the value of x-axis and y-axis. Change the value as you wish but main body under the Scaffold widget has to be Stack and this Align widget will be on the children part. Only then this will work as desired.